# Textboxes get filled when id is selected in react.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

I want to fill the textboxes when i select id from the dropdown.Textboxes get populate from mongodb. I am using reactjs/nodejs/expressjs/mongodb technologies.Can anybody guide me for this

Comment: You're asking for a "full tutorial" and this is way to broad a question to ask. if you have some of the code and need help with "part of it", then you can ask questions about that. Full "end to end" tutorials require far to much detail and tend to be very opinionated anyway. Read some existing articles and try something first, then ask questions about the specific "bits" you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Like a broad question, a broad answer.

1. Use `onChange` of your `<select>` to call the api
2. set the return data from api to a state,
3. `map` through this state in your render and return an array of `<input>` with value props

say state object datas,

inside render,

```
this.state.datas((data)=><input type="text" value={data}/>)
```